# Share memory in Windows_7 between different sessions

Tags: security, shared-memory

I using the following example to use shared memory [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx) (This is Microsoft's example).

Generally, it works just fine.
My problem starts if the "first program" is a child process of w Windows Service and the "second program" is a normal user program. In this case "second program" gets an "Access denied" error while calling OpenFileMapping().

So, I understand that I have to work with the "security descriptor", and allow all users to share this memory.
Does anyone have a clue as to how this should be done ?
I did not find any code example for this.

I saw another discussion regarding this issue he [Sharing memory between two processes (C, Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200998/sharing-memory-between-two-processes-c-windows), but that was more simple.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There was another thread [How to share memory between services and user processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898683/how-to-share-memory-between-services-and-user-processes/898863?s=12|0.2311#898863) which may help to resolve your problem. I played around with this, and using ACE

```
D:(A;;GR;;;AU)(A;;GA;;;LS)
```

ended up in that users can only READ from the shared memory.